# Tkinter GUI of real time multiple graphs

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I have asked this before and maybe I was not clear so, asking again. I am taking 4 different sensor values from arduino and plotting them real time using matplotlib of python. The real time plotting of multiple sensors is working, but I need them in a GUI with a start and a stop button. How do I modify my following code such that I get 4 real time plots in a GUI. This code is working, I just need to see my graphs in a GUI. Thanks in advance and help me the additional modification as I am new to python and still learning.

```
import copy
from threading import Thread
from tkinter import Tk, Frame

import serial
import time
import collections
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import struct

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg

A = 0
B = 0
C = 0
D = 0
Sum = 0
Az = 0
El = 0


class serialPlot:
    def __init__(self, serialPort='com5', serialBaud=38400, plotLength=100, dataNumBytes=2, numPlots=1):
        self.port = serialPort
        self.baud = serialBaud
        self.plotMaxLength = plotLength
        self.dataNumBytes = dataNumBytes
        self.numPlots = numPlots
        self.rawData = bytearray(numPlots * dataNumBytes)
        self.dataType = None
        if dataNumBytes == 2:
            self.dataType = 'h'  # 2 byte integer
        elif dataNumBytes == 4:
            self.dataType = 'f'  # 4 byte float
        self.data = []
        self.privateData = None  # for storing a copy of the data so all plots are synchronized
        for i in range(numPlots):  # give an array for each type of data and store them in a list
            self.data.append(collections.deque([0] * plotLength, maxlen=plotLength))
        self.isRun = True
        self.isReceiving = False
        self.thread = None
        self.plotTimer = 0
        self.previousTimer = 0

        print('Trying to connect to: ' + str(serialPort) + ' at ' + str(serialBaud) + ' BAUD.')
        try:
            self.serialConnection = serial.Serial(serialPort, serialBaud, timeout=4)
            print('Connected to ' + str(serialPort) + ' at ' + str(serialBaud) + ' BAUD.')
        except:
            print("Failed to connect with " + str(serialPort) + ' at ' + str(serialBaud) + ' BAUD.')

    def readSerialStart(self):
        if self.thread == None:
            self.thread = Thread(target=self.backgroundThread)
            self.thread.start()
            # Block till we start receiving values
            while self.isReceiving != True:
                time.sleep(0.1)

    def getSerialData(self, frame, lines, lineValueText, lineLabel, timeText, pltNumber):
        if pltNumber == 0:  # in order to make all the clocks show the same reading
            currentTimer = time.perf_counter()
            self.plotTimer = int((currentTimer - self.previousTimer) * 1000)  # the first reading will be erroneous
            self.previousTimer = currentTimer
        self.privateData = copy.deepcopy(
            self.rawData)  # so that the 4 values in our plots will be synchronized to the same sample time
        timeText.set_text('Plot Interval = ' + str(self.plotTimer) + 'ms')
        data = self.privateData[(pltNumber * self.dataNumBytes):(self.dataNumBytes + pltNumber * self.dataNumBytes)]
        value, = struct.unpack(self.dataType, data)

        self.data[pltNumber].append(value)  # we get the latest data point and append it to our array
        lines.set_data(range(self.plotMaxLength), self.data[pltNumber])
        lineValueText.set_text('[' + lineLabel + '] = ' + str(value))
        if lineLabel == 'Detector A':
            global A
            A = float(value)
        if lineLabel == 'Detector B':
            global B
            B = float(value)
        if lineLabel == 'Detector C':
            global C
            C = float(value)
        if lineLabel == 'Detector D':
            global D
            D = float(value)
        Sum = (A + B + C + D)
        Az = (A + D - C - B)
        El = (A + B - C - D)


    def backgroundThread(self):  # retrieve data
        time.sleep(1.0)  # give some buffer time for retrieving data
        self.serialConnection.reset_input_buffer()
        while (self.isRun):
            self.serialConnection.readinto(self.rawData)
            self.isReceiving = True

    def close(self):
        self.isRun = False
        self.thread.join()
        self.serialConnection.close()
        print('Disconnected...')


def makeFigure(xLimit, yLimit, title):
    xmin, xmax = xLimit
    ymin, ymax = yLimit
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = plt.axes(xlim=(xmin, xmax), ylim=(int(ymin - (ymax - ymin) / 10), int(ymax + (ymax - ymin) / 10)))
    ax.set_title(title)
    ax.set_xlabel("Time")
    ax.set_ylabel("Detector Output")
    ax.grid(True)
    return fig, ax


class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, figure, master, SerialReference):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.entry = None
        self.setPoint = None
        self.master = master        # a reference to the master window
        self.serialReference = SerialReference      # keep a reference to our serial connection so that we can use it for bi-directional communicate from this class
        self.initWindow(figure)     # initialize the window with our settings

    def initWindow(self, figure):
        self.master.title("Real Time Plot")
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, master=self.master)
        #toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, self.master)
        #canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)


def main():
    portName = 'COM5'
    # portName = '/dev/ttyUSB0'
    baudRate = 38400
    maxPlotLength = 100  # number of points in x-axis of real time plot
    dataNumBytes = 4  # number of bytes of 1 data point
    numPlots = 4  # number of plots in 1 graph
    s = serialPlot(portName, baudRate, maxPlotLength, dataNumBytes, numPlots)  # initializes all required variables
    s.readSerialStart()  # starts background thread


    # plotting starts below
    pltInterval = 50  # Period at which the plot animation updates [ms]
    lineLabelText = ['Detector A', 'Detector B', 'Detector C', 'Detector D']
    title = ['Detector A', 'Detector B', 'Detector C', 'Detector D']
    xLimit = [(0, maxPlotLength), (0, maxPlotLength), (0, maxPlotLength), (0, maxPlotLength)]
    yLimit = [(-1, 1), (-1, 1), (-1, 1), (-1, 1)]
    style = ['r-', 'g-', 'b-', 'y-']  # linestyles for the different plots
    anim = []
    for i in range(numPlots):
        fig, ax = makeFigure(xLimit[i], yLimit[i], title[i])
        lines = ax.plot([], [], style[i], label=lineLabelText[i])[0]
        timeText = ax.text(0.50, 0.95, '', transform=ax.transAxes)
        lineValueText = ax.text(0.50, 0.90, '', transform=ax.transAxes)

        anim.append(
            animation.FuncAnimation(fig, s.getSerialData, fargs=(lines, lineValueText, lineLabelText[i], timeText, i),
                                    interval=pltInterval))  # fargs has to be a tuple

        plt.legend(loc="upper left")
    plt.show()

    s.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Are you asking someone to write the GUI for you?

Comment: Or explain it to me how I can place the graphs in the GUI, considering my requirements.

Comment: A pretty broad explanation would be to, run threads that read the sensors, then give this info to graphs and in the main thread have graphs plotted already. About how to plot graphs tho there are multiple resources online: [for example this source](https://datatofish.com/matplotlib-charts-tkinter-gui/)

Comment: @Matiiss Yes, I've tried that. But it didn't turned out to be expected. I was plotting the graphs in the GUI, but they were not updating in real time, they were still at one point.

Comment: did You use threads tho? How were You trying to update them? also for that could You provide a [mre] of the issue with plots not updating because that would help someone solve Your problem instead of putting the whole code here where most of it is irrelevant to plots not being updated in real time

Comment: Okay, I didn't use threads. I was using some regular looping. Could you explain in detail in will and how threads will solve my problem.